# Potassium Permeability in Cardiac Muscle Cells

Tags: physiology, cardiology, electrophysiology, action-potential

From my research it seems as though there's a difference between cardiac and skeletal muscle cells in that during depolarisation, the permeability of potassium actually decreases for cardiac muscle cells. How does this occur? I imagine it would be due to the closure of potassium channels but if this is the case, then how is the inwards current of calcium balanced during the plateau phase?

Answer (score 1):

In skeletal muscles, depolarization occurs via opening of voltage-gated sodium channels, leading to influx of sodium ions, and opening of potassium channels. However, in the case of cardiac muscles, during depolarization, voltage-gated sodium channels open, and influx of sodium ions leads to closure of potassium channels, which eventually leads to the long action potential and plateau phase. In cardiac muscles, co-occurrence of calcium channels also occurs.

You can find more details [here](https://doi.org/10.1080%2F19336950.2015.1076597)